# boost ref of an instance of a class assigned to boost function

Tags: boost, function-pointers

I came across the following code where Foo is any user-defined class:

`boost::function<return_type (parameter)> f = boost::ref(instanceOfFoo);`

And I have the following Qs:
1. What happens if you assign an instance of a class to the boost function pointer? I thought we could only assign functions to it.
2. Why is the boost ref sent and not just the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `boost::function` (and C++11's `std::function`) wrap [callable objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable), which are any object that can be invoked like a function. This includes both ordinary functions and functors. [A functor is a class or struct that that defines `operator()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).
2. The [`boost::function` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp135801872) explains why you might want to wrap a reference to a functor instead of the function itself:

> In some cases it is expensive (or semantically incorrect) to have
>   Boost.Function clone a function object. In such cases, it is possible
>   to request that Boost.Function keep only a reference to the actual
>   function object. This is done using the ref and cref functions to wrap
>   a reference to a function object:

Comment: So effectively, assigning a functor instance to a boost function pointer is like assigning the operator()() "function" to it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but take note that you are binding not only the `operator()` member function but also the member variable state of the instance that the function may use.